# Make a part of a java program wait... not the whole program

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a flower game that is supposed to drop flowers at predetermined times. I have a level class and level1() is a method. Inside the level1 method i use...

```
Thread.wait(10000);
```

but it makes the whole program wait until it hits that mark. I want the program to load up then do the wait. I also tried...

```
public static void waiting(int n) {        
    long t0, t1;

    t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    do{
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    while (t1 - t0 < n);
}
```

But it does not make any difference either. Is there a better way to do this?
Here is the methods code...

```
    package net.blockydigital;

    public class Level {
        RedFlower rf;
        PinkFlower pf;
        WhiteFlower wf;
        YellowFlower yf;
        public Level(){
            rf = new RedFlower();
            pf = new PinkFlower();
            wf = new WhiteFlower();
            yf = new YellowFlower();
        }
        public void level1(){
            try{
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            rf.dropFlower();
        }
     }
```

And then this is where i call the code...

```
    public PlayGame(){
    sc = new ShoppingCart();
    pf = new PinkFlower();
    rf = new RedFlower();
    wf = new WhiteFlower();
    yf = new YellowFlower();
    s = new Shoes();
    l = new Level();
    addKeyListener(new AL());
    setFocusable(true);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    clock = new Timer(5, this);
    clock.start();
    l.level1();
}
```

I hope adding this code helps!!!

Comment: How many threads does your program have? Also, your second chunk of code is simply horrible - never use that in preference to calling `sleep` on a thread.

Comment: Im only using one thread in the program and it is that one...

Comment: If you have just one thread and call `sleep`, nothing else will happen in your application until the sleep finishes. Are you sure you don't need more than one thread?

Comment: Iguess i will need more than one thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no Java experience, but you should simply call the level1 method in another thread than the main thread. This way the program runs and the thread.sleep is only there for the level1 method.